# Solr does not search while Indexing via dataimport handler

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrcloud

I am not able to search for the data while indexing.

Indexing is done via the dataimport handler.

While searching for the documents (in between indexing is happening), it gives the broken pipe exception and wont search anything.
What should be the proper solution for this problem?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is documents indexed but not yet committed when the query send in, and the [**newsearcher**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#newSearcher) is not ready for taking queries. Have you followed suggestions about [**"Solr Near Realtime Search"**](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch)? In any case, you can tune the soft/hard commit configuration to come up a practical setup for your case.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a result of a timeout on the client side. Your solr index is likely fairly busy and is not responding in time. I don't know what client you are using to search in solr but I'd take a look at the timeouts and try increasing it:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Broken-pipe-error-td3992667.html

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Broken-pipe-td4065632.html